# VB.NET Draw on top of rectangle e.Graphics

Tags: vb.net, graphics, png

I want to draw to my form using `e.Graphics`. So I've drawn a set of rectangles (for the chess tiles for the game I'm making) and now I want to draw the pieces on top of the already drawn (and working) rectangles. The chess pieces are transparent png's saved in my `Resources` folder. I have no problem drawing them normally, but whenever I want to draw them on top of the tiles, only the tiles are visible - regardless of which line of code goes first. How do I add the pieces on top of the tiles, so the tiles are underneath?

This is the problematic code:

```
If Not alreadydrawn Then
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenbuffer)
    Checked = False
    For y = 1 To 8
        For x = 1 To 8
            If Checked Then g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, (x * 85) - 40, (y * 85) - 40, 85, 85)
            If Not Checked Then g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, (x * 85) - 40, (y * 85) - 40, 85, 85)
            Checked = Not Checked
        Next
        Checked = Not Checked
    Next
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.Bishop_White, New Rectangle(New Point(50, 50), New Size(64, 64)))
    alreadydrawn = True
End If
e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(screenbuffer, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Size(795, 805)))
```

Comment: Um, why don't you just create an empty board resource, set up a picture box and point it at that, then draw your piece(s) on top of it in a transparent control on top.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson what do you mean by board resource? A bitmap?

Comment: Aye. That way you don't have to keep redrawing it. As your pieces redraw, winders will take care of the board itself. Besides it's not going to change, why keep repainting it?

Comment: That's what I'm doing with `alreadydrawn = True`. My issue is that I can't see both at once. [This](http://imgur.com/51vYLpN) is what happens when I try to add one on top of the other. I.e. the pieces I have added (see `Bishop_White`) aren't showing up.

Comment: Not  my point at all. Draw the board on one control, draw the pieces on an other transparent control on top of it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. How do I make a picturebox transparent. `.BackColor = Color.Transparent`? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I made:

```
checked = False
For y = 1 To 8
    For x = 1 To 8
        If clickedsquare(0) = x - 1 And clickedsquare(1) = y - 1 And Not boardlayout(y - 1, x - 1) = 0 And clickmode = "options" Then
            t.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(225, 212, 128)), x * 75, y * 75, 75, 75)
        Else
            If checked Then t.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)), x * 75, y * 75, 75, 75)
            If Not checked Then t.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224)), x * 75, y * 75, 75, 75)
        End If
        checked = Not checked
    Next
    checked = Not checked
Next
```

...

Then:

```
tiles.Image = tilebuffer
pieces.Image = piecebuffer
BackgroundImage = tiles.Image
pieces.BackColor = Color.Transparent
alreadydrawn = True
```